# Going from PIC to ARM

Tags: pic, embedded, arm

I've been wanting to expand my embedded skillset with ARM MCUs after spending a few months working with pic24 devices but I've hit a roadblock. I wanted to start programming ARM more "on the metal" without the abstraction layers that things like mbed provide, similar to how I would expect to program a pic and I intended to do this with MCUXpresso. The development board I am using is the FRDM KL25Z which has an mkl25z4 on it. I was expecting to be able to find a datasheet for the chip, read that and understand how to start controlling ports, peripherals etc. but I just can't seem to find that information anywhere. I have MCUXpresso correctly configured and have installed the SDK from NXPs website and have even got a flashing LED demo up and running but only have a vague idea on how any of the code works. What information should I be looking for to help me understand better what is going on? Do datasheets of ARM based chips exist just like PIC, should I be able to read and understand the datasheet in order to control peripherals just like pic etc? Any help would be great

Comment: Sure there is a datasheet for every Controller on the market. How should it be possible to programm the controller without information. In your case you should be able to find the programming manual on the NXP website.

Comment: The problem is that the "datasheet" that the website directs to contains purely electrical information and has no information regarding SFRs, ports etc. : https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/KL25P80M48SF0.pdf In addition, usually there is example code provided within the datasheet on how to enable peripherals etc.

Comment: At ST, you have to dig deep for detailed info.  The spec covers the hardware, but there's user manuals, programming references, and dozens of app notes delving into various peripherals, subsystems, and APIs.

Comment: If you found the datasheet then you must have been to the [NXP product page](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/kinetis-cortex-m-mcus/l-seriesultra-low-powerm0-plus/kinetis-kl2x-72-96mhz-usb-ultra-low-power-microcontrollers-mcus-based-on-arm-cortex-m0-plus-core:KL2x?) for that micro. But what you're looking for is the [**Reference Manual**](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/KL25P80M48SF0RM.pdf), not the datasheet. I made the same mistake when switching from PIC to ARM a few years ago :P

Comment: @brhans that is exactly what I am looking for!! There is about 100 different documents on the product page and I managed to miss it. Please change your comment to an answer and I'll mark it. Again, thank you

Comment: Is this controller still in production? Does it have any safety features? Then the datasheet might not be available without registration on the nxp website?